# Why does AWS boto3 call to associate_iam_instance_profile cause InvalidParameterValue for invalid name when the name is valid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have code that is calling AWS boto3 APIs.  This code does several things using an iam client and an ec2 client:

```
iam_client = boto3.client('iam')
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
```

For all of these calls the role name and the profile name are the same: MyExampleName

1. Invoke `iam_client.create_instance_profile` to create a new instance profile
2. Invoke `iam_client.create_role` to create a new role
3. Invoke `iam_client.attach_role_policy` to attach an AWS-managed policy to the new role
4. Invoke `iam_client.add_role_to_instance_profile` to add the new role to the instance profile
5. Invoke `ec2_client.associate_iam_instance_profile` to associate the profile to an instance

But the last call is failing with a message such as this:

> INFO "FAILED: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling
> the AssociateIamInstanceProfile operation: Value (MyExampleName) for
> parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance
> Profile name, Account Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXX, Resource: EC2 instance:
> i-78sd976sd6912"

I just created the profile, so how is it that the call to associate_iam_instance_profile is saying it is invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of a timing issue using both the IAM client and the EC2 client.  The profile created via the `iam_client` may not *immediately* be usable by the `ec2_client`.  With some retry logic, the name seems to eventually work--it isn't *really* invalid, it just isn't found yet:

```
import time

logger.info('Attaching profile: MyExampleName'))
counter = 0
while counter < 60:
    try:
        ec2_client.associate_iam_instance_profile(IamInstanceProfile={'Name': 'MyExampleName'},
                                                  InstanceId='i-78sd976sd6912')
        break
    except ClientError as err:
        if err.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterValue':
            counter = counter + 1
            logger.info('The ec2 client did not find the profile yet; wait 1 second and then try again')
            time.sleep(1)
logger.info('Finally worked!')
```

The following logs show a real-world sample of log entries that show the EC2 client is **eventually consistent** with the IAM client:

```
INFO "Attaching profile: MyExampleName"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "The profile is not found yet; wait 1 second and then try again"
INFO "Finally worked!"
```

Comment: I'm upvoting it anyway since you are on the right path

Answer (score 1):

The more convenient approach would be to rely on `boto3` waiters purposely built do wait for certain resources to become available.

```
waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_profile_exists')
waiter.wait(
    InstanceProfileName='string',
    WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 123,
        'MaxAttempts': 123
    }
)
```

The problem with your approach, is that you're relying on a assumption that a resource will get created within 60 seconds, that might not be always the case. While waiters are keep polling until a resource becomes available.

To read more about available waiters https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_waiter

Comment: Thanks!  I tried it out, but I found that the waiter returns and the subsequent EC2 client call _still_ fails. In step 1, when I create the profile, I get a response that contains a profile ARN. I tried adding the waiter between my steps 4 and 5, but the call in step 5 using the EC2 client still failed.  Perhaps I should use a waiter after step 1 and before step 4, but that doesn't seem to help with the EC2 call in #5.  It still seems like it is something tied to using the EC2 client in conjunction with the IAM client.

Comment: Also, the example in the [documentation for create_instance_profile](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_instance_profile) says "The following command creates an instance profile named Webserver **that is ready to have a role attached and then be associated with an EC2 instance**."  I make that call, get back an ARN in the response, then try to associate it, but I get an error.  It seems like that documentation is incorrect--like it isn't _immediately_ ready to be associated with an EC2 instance.

Comment: I upvoted because it adds useful info to still consider even if it didn't solve my issue.